# import tensorflowでのエラー

Tags: python, tensorflow

### 前提・実現したいこと

Python3.7 では tensorflow が使用できない(?)エラーで詰まったため、 Python3.5 に変更したいと思い、以下のことを行うとエラーが表示されてしまいます。

エラーの原因がよくわからないため、考えられる原因を教えていただけないでしょうか？

1. pyenv で Python3.5 のインストール
2. `pyenv global 3.5.0`
3. `pip3 install tensorflow`
4. `python3`
   `import tensorflow`

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Users/torulab/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

現状のバージョンなどは以下の通りです。

- PC:
  mac os
- `$python3 --version`:
  Python 3.5.0
- `$pip3 -V`:

```
pip 18.0 from /Users/ユーザ名/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-18.0-py3.5.egg/pip (python 3.5)
```

- `$ pyenv versions`:

```
  system
* 3.5.0 (set by /Users/ユーザ名/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.0
  3.6.2
```

Comment: 参考: [Error importing tensorflow in anaconda on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765519/error-importing-tensorflow-in-anaconda-on-mac-osx)

Comment: macOS のバージョンはいくつですか?

Comment: macOSのバージョンは10.11.6です。

Comment: OSのバージョンを上げたら改善しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @tagaaa　解決はコメントに書くのではなく、自己回答として残していただけませんでしょうか。お願致します。参考[https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2645/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e3%82%92%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bb%e3%81%97%e3%81%84]